# Symfony2 Many-to-many unique constraint

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have a Thing entity, a Group entity, and a Year entity. Each Group belongs to a Year. However, Things have no relationship with Years. There is a many-to-many relationship between Things and Groups (a Group is made of several Things, and a Thing can belong to several Groups).

```
My\MainBundle\Entity\Group:
    type: entity
    manyToOne:
        year:
            targetEntity: Year
    manyToMany:
        things:
            targetEntity: Thing
            joinTable:
                name: groups_things
                joinColumns:
                    group_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    thing_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
```

What I would like to do is make sure that, **for a given year**, a group is unique. That is, if, for 2014, I have a Group that has Things 1, 2 and 3, I wan't to prevent the user from creating another Group with the same Year, and the same Things. However, creating another group with the same Things for another year is fine.

I'm not sure what to put in my `validation.yml` file, to prevent the user from creating several Groups with the same Things for the same Year.

I've tried:

```
My\MainBundle\Entity\Group:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [year, things]
            message: This group already exists.
```

but it doesn't work. I get an exception:

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in /var/www/vhosts/myhost.local/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1665

Comment: Based on the info you have provided I do not believe this to be possible with constraints alone. You will need to do add your own logic to validate this before inserting a new group with these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it in the `validation.yml` file (not sure it's even possible), so I added a check in the controller (in the "create" action):

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{   
    $entity = new Group();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $things_ids_in_new_group = array();

    foreach($entity->getThings() as $thing)
    {
        $things_ids_in_new_group[] = $thing->getId();
    }

    if(!empty($things_ids_in_new_group))
    {
        $groups = $em->getRepository('MyMainBundle:Group')->findBy(array('year' => $entity->getYear()));
        foreach($groups as $g)
        {
            $things_ids_in_existing_group = array();
            foreach($g->getThings() as $t)
            {
                $things_ids_in_existing_group = $t->getId();
            }
            if($things_ids_in_new_group == $things_ids_in_existing_group)
            {
                $form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError('This group already exists.'));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('groups_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('MyMainBundle:Group:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```